# Custom login form - Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, security, authentication

Does any of you have some example of Custom Spring Security Login form using REST Api? I am actually trying to create my own, and the problems I'm facing are:

  How should be named classes, is it User and Role? Cuz I seen many different versions of it.

  Where should I post JSON file with login and password?

  How should it look like?

Thanks in advance for all answers and examples of your code (github or something).

Answer (score 0):

REST APIs are usually stateless. It does not know something about a session. So i think you're looking for an basic auth to protect your API.
Or you could use openid connect and check the roles based on a token. This would give you more flexibility for pre conditions and post conditions processing a service call.

Here is a good example of openid connect with spring boot and google implementation. Other provider are adaptable. [Baeldung - Spring Security openid connect](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-openid-connect)

If you're just looking for a simple solution with basic auth, take a look here
[Baeldung - Spring Security basic auth](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-basic-authentication)

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use form login and rest API together, but that means that your rest API isn't going to be stateless, it means that a session will be created and rest APIs are usually stateless, that's why you have to use basic auth, jwt, etc when creating a rest API, but if you really want to use rest API with form-based authentication, I made an example for you, check this [link](https://github.com/ronaldogeldres/custom-login-rest-api)

This example uses Spring Boot, Spring MVC, H2, Spring Security with custom form login, Spring Data Jpa, but again it's not recommended to use form login for rest API.

Regarding to your questions

**How should be named classes, is it User and Role? Cuz I seen many different versions of it.**

- It's up to you

**Where should I post JSON file with login and password?**

- If you are using spring security form-based authentication, there no need to post a json